# Getting attribute of element in ng-click function in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a span tag like below which call a function in the controller when clicked.

**HTML**

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="event in events">
    <div class="col-lg-1 text-center">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" data={{event.id}} ng-click="deleteEvent()">
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.deleteEvent=function(){
    console.log(this);
}
```

I need to get the value in data attribute in the controller function. I tried using this keyword and $event; neither one worked.

Please help.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Try passing it directly to the ng-click function:

```
<div class="col-lg-1 text-center">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" data="{{event.id}}"
          ng-click="deleteEvent(event.id)"></span>
</div>
```

Then it should be available in your handler:

```
$scope.deleteEvent=function(idPassedFromNgClick){
    console.log(idPassedFromNgClick);
}
```

Here's [an example](http://jsfiddle.net/jandersen/RUnaE/)

Comment: Actually this whole div comes inside ng-repeat. So i cannot use event.id inside ng-click. I think.

Comment: Check out the jsFiddle link I just added to my answer for an example of using a parameter to `ngClick` within `ngRepeat`

Answer (score 83):

Even more simple, pass the `$event` object to `ng-click` to access the event properties. As an example:

```
<a ng-click="clickEvent($event)" class="exampleClass" id="exampleID" data="exampleData" href="">Click Me</a>
```

Within your `clickEvent() = function(obj) {}` function you can access the `data` value like this:

```
var dataValue = obj.target.attributes.data.value;
```

Which would return `exampleData`.

Here's a [full jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/FAeJq/).

Comment: Your jsFiddle works fine in Chrome, but not in FireFox ?

Comment: Thanks for catching this. I've udpated the jsFiddle with a better solution using `obj.target`.

Comment: I found out you can do `obj.target.getAttribute("data")` looks more readable IMO, js fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/zpApT/

Comment: Note that if you have a custom data-attribute such as `data-example-attr="whatever"` then you would need to refer to it like so in your JS: `obj.toElement.dataset.exampleAttr`

Comment: @carmat's solution didn't seem to work on FF (worked on Chrome though),  functional-rocking's obj.target.getAttribute("data-example-attr") worked for me with both Chrome && FF.

Comment: This solution was perfect for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Addition to the answer of Brett DeWoody: (which is updated now)

```
var dataValue = obj.srcElement.attributes.data.nodeValue;
```

Works fine in IE(9+) and Chrome, but Firefox does not know the srcElement property.
I found:

```
var dataValue = obj.currentTarget.attributes.data.nodeValue;
```

Works in IE, Chrome and FF, I did not test Safari.

Comment: Thanks Michiel. I've updated the jsFiddle to address this. I'm using the more universal `obj.target` property to grab attributes now.

Comment: Yes Brett, I agree it's better to use target, updating my code, Thanks!