# angularJs on ng-submit serialize form (ajax way)

Tags: jquery, angularjs, cakephp

First of all, my back-end is using cakePHP 2.3 so I will like to have ajax way serialize all.

currently i have a form to test if serialize function working

```
//index
<http ng-app="app">...
<div ng-controller="appCtrl" ng-model='data'>...
<form ng-submit="helloWorld(this)" onsubmit="event.returnValue = false; return false;">
...</form><div></http>

//app.js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller("appCtrl", function($scope){
    $scope.helloWorld = function(element){
        console.log(element);
    }
});
```

however it just return a bunch of item. tried $(element.target).serialize() but it cannot work. Finding an equivalent way of doing data: $(element.target).serialize() .

JsFiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/eX7fB/

version 2 for explain http://jsfiddle.net/eX7fB/1/

Comment: How are you binding data to your form?  Can you show the form markup?

Comment: as above code `//index`

Answer (score 2):

Here is an [updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7WmZ5/).

In order to pull form data out of an angular form, it is best to use name your form and use `ng-model` on the input elements:

HTML:

```
<form name="form1" ng-submit="helloWorld()">
    <input name="color" ng-model="color" type="text">
    <input name="range" ng-model="range" type="text">
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
 </form>
```

JS:

```
$scope.helloWorld = function(){
    console.log($scope.form1);
    console.log($scope.color);
    console.log($scope.range);
    alert($scope.form1);
    alert($scope.color);
    alert($scope.range);
}
```

Documentation for forms is [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms).

Comment: I don't see your updated jsFiddle.Btw, have added a more reallife CakePHP jsFiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/eX7fB/1/) to explain the condition. I need to serialize it including the hidden token

Comment: your jsfiddle is just the standard angular way of doing the problem. Needa passback data in something like `_method=POST&data%5B_Token%5D%5Bkey%5D=a5b339e9083ae1a4cc675f27bf7fa820a9ccfbac&data%5B_Token......`

Comment: my version 2 jsFiddle link explained the situation

Comment: How do you serialize a form?

Answer (score 2):

I have found the easiest way to get form data is by creating an object that will contain all the models of the form. Since you don't need to specify each model from the controller you can just create an empty object that will eventually contain all the form information.

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.form = {};
  $scope.submitform = function(){
     console.log($scope.form)
  }
});
```

You do have to specify the model bindings in the HTML `<input type="text" ng-model="form.name">` but now the **form object** will contain other object called **name**.

You can now pass the form object to ajax data.

Check [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/I8rbGPY8YIHSGGFzHCqe) to see the example I have created.
Hope this helps.

**UPDATE**

Hi there. Ok I probably misunderstood your question. If you really need to serialise the form [check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/juanpa_solano/yqxLM/) to see if that is what your looking for. You have to pass the **$event** object in **ng-submit** and not **this**, and then you can treat the event with normal jQuery stuff. Although I really doubt  this is a good practice.

Comment: pardon me you're still specifying the model binding in your plunker example, and somehow this doesn't work with hidden input ( unless you change it with `display:none` )

Comment: I have misunderstood you. See the update to see if this time i can help you.

Comment: the answer I provided below is using event, well I love hybrid things. Since this is for the CakePHP so it should follow the KISS theory ( although I'm integrating with new framework currently )

Answer (score 1):

I've make you a alternative method of serialize referring to  [Getting attribute of element in ng-click function in angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18029261/getting-attribute-of-element-in-ng-click-function-in-angularjs/18030442#18030442)

Though some may said that this is not angular way, but since you are using cakePHP as back end, why not just Keep It Simple Silly.( saving lots of space from adding ng-model and rebuilding the form-helper. And saved lots of space.

```
//index
<http ng-app="app">...
<div ng-controller="appCtrl" ng-model='data'>...
<form ng-submit="helloWorld($event)" onsubmit="event.returnValue = false; return false;">
...</form><div></http>

//app.js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller("appCtrl", function($scope){
    $scope.helloWorld = function(obj){
        console.log(obj);
        alert($(obj.target).serialize());
    }
});
```