# How to send current div's id into a function when clicked

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I'm trying to send a div's id into a function as a parameter when clicked.

But it is not working.

Here's what I have written, please take a look :

```
<div id="currentId" ng-click="functionCalled(id)">
</div>
```

Comment: Is it a string you're passing in as an id? If so have you tried ng-click="functionCalled('currentId')" ?

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22630613/3455035)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit your code with,
**HTML:**

```
<button id="bla" class="button button-light" data-ng-click="functionCalled($event)">
    Click Me
</button>
```

**JS:**

```
$scope.functionCalled= function(event){
    alert(event.target.id);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll give it a try :)

Comment: Sure, I'll do that :)

Comment: Still waiting :) @Harish

Comment: Sorry bro, I totally forgot about it. Yes, it's working perfectly. Thank you so much :)

Comment: Very helpful to pass value from button click to function

Answer (score 1):

try to use following method with this object  `<div id="currentId" ng-click="functionCalled(this.id)">
</div>`

Answer (score 1):

The click event function has the event as an argument.

```
<div id="currentId" ng-click="functionCalled(event)">
```

Now you can access the properties from the target property in the in the event argument.

```
function functionCalled(event){
   let id = event.target.id; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="currentId" ng-click="functionCalled($event)">
</div>
```

In your controller

```
functionCalled($event){
//use $event.target.id
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can pass this as $event

```
 <div id="currentId" ng-click="functionCalled($event)"></div>
```

and use this as

```
 e.target.attributes.id.value
```